# executable cant find files when run as service

Tags: systemd

I'm learning to make a small web server as a part of learning rust, which is hosted on an embedded linux system. I compile the software on my laptop, scp the binary and the other files over to the embedded system and then restart the service that launches my web server.

However when I navigate to the IP of my webserver it crashes when trying to GET the first HTML file with a no such file or directory error.

When I manually execute the server via an ssh connection it works fine and the page loads perfectly.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the root that the executable gets from systemd, but I cannot find any file path that works, relative or absolute.

Can someone explain what is going on and how I can get it to work. I don't want to have to manually execute the file everytime I make a change, I just want to execute my upload script locally.

current files are like so /home/web_server is the executable
and /home/index.html is my HTML file it should send to the client.

I can't even get it to work with:

```
use std::{
    env,
    path::Path,
}
let root = Path::new("/home/");
assert!(env::set_current_dir(&root).is_ok());
```

.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Web server service
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/web_server
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

The embedded system is running debian 11 on kernel 5.10.72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put `WorkingDirectory=/home`
in the `[service]` field of my `.service` file to fix the executed file's working directory.